# Can I sort an array of pointers in order to remove duplicates?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior

Let's say I defined a structure and created a few instances of it. I have an array of pointers to these instances but some pointers point to the same instances of my structure. I want to remove duplicates in the array so I sort it by `qsort()` function. Here's my comparison function:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  struct foo **s1 = (struct foo**)a;
  struct foo **s2 = (struct foo**)b;
  return *s1 - *s2;
}
```

The question is, can I really sort using such a comparison? I know that subtructing pointers is undefined in this case but I care only about the integer value of pointers, because I simply want pointers pointing to the same instance of `foo` to be next to each other.

Maybe I should use function like this:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  struct foo **s1 = (struct foo**)a;
  struct foo **s2 = (struct foo**)b;
  if (*s1 > *s2)
    return 1;
  else if (*s1 == *s2)
    return 0;
  else 
    return -1;
}
```

Is there any difference in using them?

Comment: Why do you think subtracting pointer will invoke UB?

Comment: If inserting duplicates is likely, you should think of avoiding them in the first place.

Comment: @haccks I'm not sure if subtracting two pointers always gives result with the same sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `intptr_t` (which is an integer type), then you can cast your `void*` pointers to that, and then you can compare arbitrary values. `intptr_t` is not a required type, but it is pretty common in practice.

Subtracting one `intptr_t` from another might still overflow, so it is not a strictly portable solution. But comparison is fine. If you used `uintptr_t` to avoid overflow, the difference will never be negative. That's a general problem with using `a - b` to implement qsort-style compare functions.

Subtracting or comparing pointers which don't point into the same object is undefined behaviour. So neither of the proposed solutions in the question are valid:

§6.5.6 para 9 (Additive operators):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object

§6.5.8 para 5 provides a list of possible valid comparisons, which is a bit more generous than the restriction on subtraction, since you can compare pointers to two members of the same `struct` or `union`, provided the members themselves are of the same type. But unrelated objects do not fall into any of this list. It terminates with the sentence: "In all other cases, the behavior is undefined."

If you want a truly portable solution which doesn't depend on `intptr_t`, then you could memcmp the pointers. But, really, I think that is only of theoretical interest.

Comment: An approach using `uintptr_t`, when such a type exists and is reasonably defined, should never result in Undefined Behavior (though I don't think anything in the standard would forbid the existence of a `uintptr_t` which couldn't hold all pointer values), but it wouldn't be guaranteed to work.  If a system with a 16-bit memory bus used 48-bit pointers but `uintptr_t` was 64 bits, it would be perfectly legitimate for `uintptr_t x=p;` to store `p` into the lower 48 bits of `x` and leave the top 16 bits holding arbitrary values if those uninitialized bits would be ignored when converting back.

Comment: If `uintptr_t` is defined reasonably, then the fact that two pointers of the same type yield the same `uintptr_t` value should imply that they would compare equal, and on *most* systems the reverse comparison would hold true as well, but nothing in the C Standard would preclude the existence of a system which deliberately made it *impossible* for code to define any form of ranking among pointers to unknown objects by *any* means, even using bit-level hacks.

Comment: @supercat: Yep, it's implementation-defined. In theory, the mapping from void*->intptr_t might not be bijective. It seems clear that given `void *p, *q`, (uintptr_t)p==(uintptr_t)q implies that p==q, because `(void*)(uintptr_t)p` must be equal to `p`, but as you say, it is theoretically possible that `(uintptr_t)p` is not a function. In C++, this whole issue can be avoided because `std::less<T*>` is guaranteed to be a total order. But afaik there is no way to backport that guarantee to C.

Comment: I wish the C standards committee would recognize that if 99% of platforms can easily support a behavior, there would be great value in having a defined means by which code can ask if it's supported.  For example, have a standard macro `__STDC_UNRELATED_PTR_COMPARE` which would be 1 if the compiler could guarantee that relational operators would yield 0 or 1, but made no promises beyond that, and higher numbers would represent various stronger guarantees, up to a guarantee that all pointers are ranked, and addresses identifying parts of distinct objects will rank distinctly.

Comment: I understand that allowing unrelated pointer comparisons to yield Undefined Behavior makes C usable on platforms that don't support them, and I have no problem with that.  I find absurd, however, the idea that the inability of some rare platforms to support such a feature constitutes a good reason to forbid the use of that feature *within programs that will never need to run on such rare platforms*.  If an old compiler for a common platform allows such comparisons, but a newer optimizer will regard relational comparisons among pointers as justifying an assumption that they identify the same...

Comment: ...objects, and will thus malfunction badly when unrelated pointers are compared, I find it hard to view the new compiler as an "improvement".

Comment: @supercat: The experience of C++ is that it is sufficient to define a standard library function, say `pointer_compare`. Now that C has even the limited generics it has, that would easily be definable in C and would avoid this particular problem. Although I sympathize with your opinion, too.

Comment: I wouldn't particularly mind having the standard define macros like `__PTR_GT()` which, if included in an implementation, are specified to compare two arbitrary pointers with defined semantics.  Code which requires such macros could be made to work with older compilers where `>` works as required by including a "compatibility header" `#define __PTR_GT(x,y) ((x)>(y))`.  I would suggest, though, that the only reason people continue to use C rather than defining a new language is to maintain continuity with existing code bases, and that the language should give some priority...

Comment: ...to allowing production code which works on one platform to be migrated to newer platforms while retaining the same semantics.  Further, I would suggest that in the very common real-world scenario where a program must exhibit precisely-defined behavior when given valid input and loosely-defined behavior when given invalid input, requiring programmers to absolutely positively avoid invoking anything the Standard would deem "Undefined Behaivor" will result in compilers having fewer optimization opportunities than they could have had if the Standard imposed some constraints (e.g. saying that...

Comment: ...the expression `a<<b` is required to shift left `b` times when `b` is 0 to the number of bits in `int`, and may shift it left any arbitrarily number of times from 0 to (unsigned long)b when `b` is larger than that).  If `b` is a byte being read from a file, `a<<(b & 31)` will on many processors be slower than `a<<b`; if code doesn't care how much things get shifted with `b` values from 32 to 255, and doesn't care if shifting 255 bits takes eight times as long as shifting 31, but merely wants to preserve the laws of causality, the tighter spec would allow code to be more optimizable.)

Comment: @supercat: I suspect that few members of the std C committee will read this comment thread; SO comments are not really intended for discussions of this sort, interesting though they may be. In general, it is less difficult to propose standard library additions than language changes. My point about C++ is that it requires that pointers be comparable, even if in a particular implementation there is no way of doing so with only the standard operators and APIs. The standard library can use other techniques. Requiring the feature is better than a feature-test macro. Good luck with the submission.

Comment: I wouldn't see something like `__STDC_UNRELATED_PTR_COMPARE` as a language change, but merely as an acknowledgment of an widely-supported and widely-used extension.  As for "submission", where/how would I "submit" something?

Comment: @supercat: There are some contacts here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/contacts ; I believe you're supposed to work through your national body. You could also try https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.C

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates, then you can use a nested for loop to go through each pointer, like so:

```
int duplicates=0;
for (int i=0;i<count;++i;)
    for (int j=i+1;j<count;++j)
        if (data [i]==data [j])
            ++duplicates;
```

Then allocate enough memory for `count-duplicates` pointers, and then loop through the original data set and only copy over ones that you haven't copied yet. It's inefficient, but it will work.